# Subprocess not opening files

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I am writing a program to open other programs for me. os.system() would always freeze my app, so I switched to subprocess.

I did some research and this is how a tutorial told me to open a program.

I have only replaced the path for my variable, which contains the path.

After I run this, only a commabd prompt window opens and nothing else. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
from subprocess import Popen
filename1 = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
Popen(["cmd", "/c", "start", filename1)
```

Comment: Have you tried with `Popen(["cmd", "/c", "start", " \""+ filename1 + "\""])`?

Comment: @noah no need to quote Popen args when it's a list (it's even counter-productive and can break things). Problem is somewhere else

Comment: "it returns an error" => can you post the exact error?. Note: `""+filename1` is exactly like `filename1`. Unless you meant to add an empty argument, in which case replace "+" by ","

Comment: in this particular case, no need cmd /c start ... just do `Popen(["C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"])` it will run in the background all right.

Comment: Well I can't just put the file path, because the file path can change and therefore I want to execute a variable

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ur right, just tested it.

Comment: Just updated the errors it produces. They're under the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
filename1 = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
subprocess.Popen(filename1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a single string with double quotes around it. In Python terms, you basically want `r'"c:\torture\thanks Microsoft"'` where the single quotes and the `r` create a Python string, which contains the file name inside double quotes.

```
from subprocess import Popen

filename1 = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
Popen(["cmd", "/c", "start", f'"{filename1}"'])
```

Quoting with CMD is always bewildering; maybe think about ways you can avoid it (or Windows altogether, if you have a choice).

Comment: It returns the same errors I listed above

Comment: using os.system() works, but freezes the program after clicking the button and is deprecated.

Comment: Try using backslashes instead of forward slashes in the filename. Windows (or specifically CMD I guess) interprets forward slashes as option specifiers in some contexts.